# video clustering in matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

i'm trying to write the code of this article:*"Improving Cluster Selection and Event Modeling in Unsupervised Mining for Automatic Audiovisual Video Structuring"*
a part of the it is about video clustering:
"The video stream is segmented into shots based on color histograms to detect abrupt changes and progressive transitions. Each of the resulting shot is summarized by a key frame, taken in the middle of the shot, in turn represented as a RGB histogram with 8 bins per color. Bottom-up clustering relies on the Euclidean distance between the 512-dimension color histograms using Ward’s linkage."
i've done this and reached to an array of numbers like this: 
1.0e+03 *

```
3.8334
3.9707
3.8887
2.1713
2.5616
2.3764
2.4533
```

that after performing the dendrogram part, the result became:

```
 174.0103
 175.0093
 176.0093
 177.0093
178.0093
 178.0093
179.0093
```

but according to a toy example that was given by authors of the article the result should be intervals like:
{47000, 50000}, {143400, 146400}, {185320, 187880},{228240, 231240}, {249440, 252000}, {346000, 349000}
what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have 512 dimensional vectors at the first step, one such vector per frame, or equivalently a 512 x n matrix.

Then in the second step I don't think they use the plain built-in hierarchical clustering - which is not time aware, and will not produce intervals, plus it will scale O(n^3) which is really bad - but instead they use a customized clustering algorithm, inspired by hierarchical clustering and using Ward's linkage, but which operates on time intervals; starting with single frames, but *only joining neighboring intervals*, not arbitrary intervals like regular hierarchical clustering would.

Comment: so you think they reached to intervals by customizing the clustering algorithm and just using the dendrogram that is in matlab wont help?

Comment: i find this article which is one of the authors works "AUTOMATIC VIDEO STRUCTURING BASED ON HMMS AND AUDIO VISUAL INTEGRATION" it was not cited in the article which i'm working on it but this occur to me that may be they use this for clustering.is it right or not? and thank you for your help

Comment: Well, I didn't read their paper. I don't think they used another paper they did not cite. But if I had to cluster a video stream, I would do it this way. Plain clustering algorithms will just not produce intervals; if you want intervals you need to put this constraint into the clustering algorithm. And this is probably such a straightforward modification, it will not be published anywhere.

Comment: thank you. i think i'm doomed i dono how to do this:( any how thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Read a good introduction to hierarchical clustering; then it should be quite obvious that instead of trying to combine arbitrary clusters, you only consider candidates that are next to each other in time. So in fact, the clustering problem actually becomes a lot easier, because you only have up to 2 neighbors to merge with.